# How to insert a hierachy triangle into an email using html

Tags: css, email, html

I have a webpage that automatically sends an email based on the template. 
In that email I want a hierarchy triangle that will uses some of the data from the page. 
The page generates results; Number of activities, number of appointments, number of proposals, number of deals.
So in the email it should have
Top of the triangle: number of activities (100)
Second level: number of appointments (30)
Third level: number of proposals (10)
Bottom: number of deals (3)

Would I be able to use HTML? Or possibly use an image and overlay text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possibility is to output the result as an .svg rather than a standard image.  SVGs are basically XML and most browsers can now render them flawlessly.  They're very simple to create and would work well with something as simple as the application you've described.

A good place to get started is here:

http://www.w3schools.com/svg/

You can see some great examples with code here:

http://www.w3schools.com/svg/svg_examples.asp

Comment: Problem: "most _BROWSERS_ can render [SVGs] flawlessly". Email clients are NOT browsers

Comment: If you look at [this css-tricks.com article](https://css-tricks.com/a-guide-on-svg-support-in-email/) it explains that Outlook 2013, Gmail, Gmail (iOS), and Android all don't support SVG in img tags (that's 40% of major email clients, & that's the scenerio where SVG get the MOST support is in images) (& in case you're curious the iOS and OSX built-in mail clients are the only ones that have full support). However, if you read to the bottom of the article, they have some interesting workarounds that substitute .jpg files when it isn't supported. Kinda a can of worms.

Comment: Huh?  https://css-tricks.com/a-guide-on-svg-support-in-email/  It says here that all the ones I listed support it except GMAIL outside Android.  I don't use GMAIL other than from my phone so didn't really expect that.  My office machine uses Office 365 / Outlook.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but not to the same extent as a full browser. Email clients vary a lot in HTML tag support, so use only basic *static* HTML tags such as `div`, `span`, `a`, or `img`. For more capabilities, you would need to link to a page that could perhaps show them more dynamic information.

That said you can do a *lot* with just just images, divs, links, and text. Even the biggest companies with really high tier developers just use these tags.

Comment: True.  SVGs would be the src used in the img tag, so I think we'd be good.  In fact, much of the email we get with embedded images are SVG and we don't even realize it.  But, I'd have to agree, for older email clients, SVGs could be an issue.  But for GMAIL, Yahoo Mail, Outlook, and other mainstream email clients, it should be OK.

Comment: @LuvnJesus Right, but an SVG is not just any normal image file type. It's XML. And it's pretty likely that it will display as text in your email if it's not supported. I think there is a great marriage between our answers that would work best, because you want to give the email SOME ability to be copy/pasted and such. But the sender shouldn't be afraid to provide a link to a more fancy webpage that can give them the business information they need. It's my understanding that this isn't an advertisement email where people would overlook the link.

Comment: @LuvnJesus So Yahoo Mail is the only client you just listed that supports SVG images

Comment: Incorrect.  I use outlook which supports it just fine.  Any other interface that uses HTML5 should also support SVG. But, the better response might be from 4castle where having link to a fancier view of the data would be the best all around as it eliminates the need for any html browser at all and then you can use any method you want to present the data.  SVG still happens to be the simplest way to do that IMO.